# jQuery Error NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, quovolver

I am using quovolver on a website I am building, when I attempt to add this script I receive this error:

```
NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0
[nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle]
[Break On This Error]   

var ret = matches.call( elem, expr );               jquery.js (line 5316
```

If I remove quovolver the error goes away.

How do I solve this issue?

Here is my HTML and JS:

***HTML***

```
<div class="quotes">   
<span>
  <blockquote>
     <p><i class="icon-quote-left"></i>Quote Goes here<i class="icon-quote-right"></i></p>
     <p>&mdash;Author</p>
  </blockquote>
</span>

<span>
     <h2>Call to Action Text</h2> 
</span>

<!-- NEXT SET OF QUOTES/CALL TO ACTION -->

</div>
```

***JS***

```
$('.quotes').quovolver({
    children : 'span',
    pauseOnHover : true,
    autoPlaySpeed : 8000
});
```

Comment: Trailing slashes in object literals make me twitchy. It's not necessarily in jQuery, it's probably somewhere in the Quovolver source. There's no elements in that markup with `class="quotes"` either. If you have a minimized version, you might try a non-minified script instead.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - I left out the containing div by accident. I edited the question to add this code. What I do not get is I have used Quovolver on other sites without issue. One other note the Quovolver code is not minified.

Comment: So switch out the references in this site with references to those other (working) site's scripts and see if it's fixed. It could be a server misconfiguration, mismatched file encoding (use UTF8 but make sure the files are in that encoding), etc. First fix it if you can, and work your way backwards until you have triangulated the problem area.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - Unfortunately no luck with getting it to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There was a bug report from jQuery 1.1 or something that reported this was due to a quirk with files with really long strings, and another around 1.2 that observed `$.html()` can have issues with certain strings and bypassing it with `.innerHTML` is recommended if it happens. And they decided not to fix it (at least back then). So. Have you confirmed it's happening on other computers running Firefox? Have you restarted your computer, updated Firefox, etc.?