# jQuery FadeIn and FadeOut causes flickering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout, flicker

I originally wrote this question about a jQuery plugin. I since attempted another code using just jQuery:

```
$('#action-alerts .rotate:gt(0)').hide();
 setInterval(function(){
    $('#action-alerts .rotate:first-child').fadeOut(600)
       .next('.rotate').delay(600).fadeIn(600)
       .end().appendTo('#action-alerts');}, 
  3000);
```

This code still has the flickering issue in iOS. How do I solve this issue?

Below is my original question:

---

I am using a jQuery Plugin called [Quote Rotator](http://coryschires.com/jquery-quote-rotator-plugin/). It works great in the browser, however, in iOS (v6) when the transition happens it flickers. It is quite annoying and I am not sure how to solve the flicker issues. I have read about `-webkit-backface-visibility` but I do not believe this is the case. First I already had this code in my stylesheet:

```
body {
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Second doesn't this just apply to CSS 3 Transitions? (Or is my understanding incorrect?)

What should I try to solve this issue?

**HTML**

```
<div id="action-alerts">
  <ul>
    <li>
       <div class="quote-holder">
       <div class="grid_10">
       <h3 class="action-box-red"><span class="alert-icon">Text</span></h3>     
       </div>
       <div class="grid_2">
       <a target="_blank" href="#" class="default_button xlarge textcenter red">Read the <br> Report</a>
       </div>
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
       <div class="quote-holder">
       <div class="grid_10">
       <h3 class="action-box-red"><span class="alert-icon">Text</span></h3>     
       </div>
       <div class="grid_2">
       <a target="_blank" href="#" class="default_button xlarge textcenter red">Take <br> Action</a>
       </div>
       </div>
    </li> 
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#action-alerts').quote_rotator({
        rotation_speed: 9000
    }); 
});
```

Notes: I have more HTML than posted here. This is a snippet. I am using jQuery 1.8.3. I do not mind changing to another plugin if it works (Meaning it creates a simple fade transition between `<li>` elements.) I have attempted to use [Quovolver](http://sebnitu.github.com/Quovolver/) before Quote Rotator but I had [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15287780/825757) and could not get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second thought, the issue is probably caused by the fact that `fadeOut` causes the element to have a `display:none` at the end of its run. Therefore, when the element goes to fade back in, first it needs to be shown. This would be that rugged "Flicker" you describe.

```
$('#action-alerts .rotate:gt(0)').fadeTo(10,0);
setInterval(function(){
    $('#action-alerts .rotate:first-child').fadeTo(1000,0, function() { 
        $('#action-alerts .rotate:first-child').next('.rotate').delay(300).fadeTo(1000,1)
          .end().appendTo('#action-alerts');
    });
}, 
3000);
```

**jsFiddle of a working example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Eznpg/12/

Comment: Thanks for the help. Couple problems. 1) After the first `div` that fades in the others will appear before the other fades out. (Note: I changed `, 6000)` to `600`. 2) After I reach the last div it doesn't start again.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first issue - perhaps could you supply us with the full HTML so that I could test it myself?

Comment: It looks great on desktop but it still has issues in iOS.

Comment: @Lynda I just tried this in safari and it looks fine ... I can't understand why IOS would have issues though, sorry.

http://jsfiddle.net/Eznpg/12/

Comment: I believe that it has to do with the javascript engine but I am not 100% sure. I have read several things along those lines. I think I may try CSS3 to see if it is any better and use jQuery as a fallback for older devices.