# Why am I getting a flickering affect using fadeTo? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

Why am I getting a flickering effect?

I checked this [question - jQuery FadeIn and FadeOut causes flickering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423614/jquery-fadein-and-fadeout-causes-flickering) and changed my code to use fadeTo instead of fading in and out. However, I still seem to be getting a flickering affect. Can anyone help?

HTML:

```
<ul class="testimonial-list">
    <li class="testimonial">
      <p>some text</p>
    </li>
    <li class="testimonial">
      <p>some text</p>
    </li>
    <li class="testimonial">
      <p>some text</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Function:

```
 function InOut( elem ){

 elem.delay(2000)
     .fadeTo(4000,1)
     .delay(2000)
     .fadeTo(4000,0,
         function(){ 
             if(elem.next().length > 0)
                 {InOut( elem.next() );}
             else
                 {InOut( elem.siblings(':'));} 
         }
     );
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.testimonial').css("opacity",0);
    InOut( $('.testimonial:first') );
```

Side note - the website in question is in Wordpress but I don't know if it is significant to the question.

Comment: Can see it in this fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/yj7fxufx/ [updated - just noticed it does recreate the problem.]

Comment: Seems smooth to me. Have you looked into just using CSS transitions?

Comment: No flickering here either (FF)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. I tested your jsfiddle in IE and Chrome. No reason it should flicker, although the WP framework *could* be interfering since it tends to be messy and bloated. You could try disabling some plugins.

You *could* switch to CSS3 animations or transitions, but the animations will not show in older browsers. And I find JS animations to play smoother anyways.

Good tut on CSS3 animations: http://www.kirupa.com/html5/introduction_to_animation_html.htm#cssAnimations_topic